# How to form a regex for a double quote that may or may not exist (Flutter)

Tags: regex, flutter

It's possible that I will either have

```
boundary=-------Embt-Boundary--1261032946D275CF
```

or

```
boundary="-------Embt-Boundary--1261032946D275CF"
```

and I want to just extract `-------Embt-Boundary--1261032946D275CF` from the String.

How should I formed the regex? I have tried `boundary="?(.+)("?)` but it only works for the first but for the second I'll get the last double quote in my extracted string (eg. `-------Embt-Boundary--1261032946D275CF"`).

The regex I need is for flutter

Comment: By the rules of [tag:regex] tag, you should also tag the tool, engine or dialect of regex you are asking about. E.g. Vim regexes are very different from Ruby (Onigmo) regexes.

Comment: @Amadan oh! i have edited the tags and my title, it's for flutter

Comment: @GillesQuénot tested but it doesnt work for me :(

Comment: @Lyn: Post edited accordingly. Try again please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe flutter is Dart, which uses JavaScript regex specification, yes? Use capture groups in this way:

```
boundary=("?)(.*)(\1)
```

Group 1 will capture a quote if there is one. Group 2 will capture your desired result. Then, `\1` will match the quote, if there was one, or nothing, if the quote was not present.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QRXuaT/1)

Answer (score 1):

##### You need:

```
boundary="?([^"]+)"?
```

Only one capture group used.

##### JS Demo:

```js
const input1 = 'boundary="-------Embt-Boundary--1261032946D275CF"';
const input2 = 'boundary=-------Embt-Boundary--1261032946D275CF';
const regex = /boundary="?([^"]+)"?/;

const match1 = regex.exec(input1);
const match2 = regex.exec(input2);

console.log(match1[1]);
console.log(match2[1]);
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `boundary=` | 'boundary=' |
| `"?` | '"' (optional (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `[^"]+` | any character except: `"` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `"?` | '"' (optional (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: Note that this will also match a string with unmatched quotation marks (i.e. `'boundary="foo'` or `'boundary=foo"'`.  It's probably good enough for the OP, but it's not sufficient if rejecting malformed strings is desired.